# Keep 2nd datepicker limited by 1st datepicker

Tags: jquery, date, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm trying to use the below snippet to control the min-date of a datepicker field based on the date selected in a previous field before it. A classic "start date" "end date" situation. I also want to change the end date to be the start date if the user changed the start date to be after the end date.

Here is what I'm trying.

```
$('#projBegins .hasDatepicker').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateStr) {         
        $('#projEnds .hasDatepicker').val(dateStr);
        $('#projEnds .hasDatepicker').datepicker('option',{ minDate: new Date(dateStr)})
    }
});
```

Comment: I figured out I was using syntax to made a new datepicker instead of editing an existing one....

Answer (score 0):

> Problem in class name "hasDatepicker".

Don't use hasDatepicker class name in your input element for datepicker. Use a different name, like date_picker.

JQuery adds the class hasDatepicker to the element that datepicker() is called on. If the element already has the class hasDatepicker, then the datepicker() function does nothing. So use a different class name.

Try following working example:

```js
$(function() {

  $("#projBegins .datepicker").datepicker({
    onClose: function(selectedDate) {
      var start = $("#projBegins .datepicker").datepicker("getDate");
      var end = $("#projEnds .datepicker").datepicker("getDate");
      alert(start);
      alert(end);
      if (start > end) {
        $('#projEnds .datepicker').val(selectedDate);
      }
      $(".end-date").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
    }
  });
  $("#projEnds .datepicker").datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="projBegins">
  <input type="text" class="datepicker">
</div>
<div id="projEnds">
  <input type="text" class="datepicker">
</div>
```

Comment: In my case, I believe it would something like this: 
$('#projBegins .hasDatepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "m/d/y",
    minDate: 0,
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
           $('#projEnds .hasDatepicker').datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
   $('#projEnds .hasDatepicker').datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        dateFormat: "m/d/y",
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $('#projBegins .hasDatepicker').datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it:

```
  startInput.datepicker('option', 'onSelect', function(date){
            expInput.datepicker('option', 'minDate', date);
        });
```